# Having trouble saving to file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cgi

Hi I have a simple form that allows a user to input a name, their gender and a password. I use Digest::MD5.hexdigest to encrypt the input. Once I have the encrypted input eg, d1c261ede46c1c66b7e873564291ebdc, I want to be able to append this to a file I have already created. However every thing I have tried just isn't working. Can anyone please help and thank you in advance. Here is what I have:

```
input = STDIN.read( ENV["CONTENT_LENGHT"] )
puts "Content-type: text/html \n\n"

require 'digest/md5'
digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(input)

f = File.open("register.txt", "a")
    f.write(digest)
f.close
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
File.open("register.txt", "a") do |f|
    f.puts(digest)
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; what isn't working? The code you have works just fine, although I don't know why you write the content-type to stdout. (I also don't get why you use an environment variable to set a variable; are you sure the typo isn't the only issue?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am newbie to Ruby and as I understand it STDIN & STDOUT are used to forms which use the POST method, which I am. To be honest with you I'm a bit confused with ruby, everything I have read, just goes over my head. All I am after is the form input to be encrypted which is then appended to a file after the form has been submitted. If I have gone the wrong way about it, please point me in the right direction. Thanks again.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Copy/pasting your code appended the digest to my file as expected (Ubuntu / Ruby 1.8.7)

Comment: Form input? Are you doing some sort of CGI thing?! I don't know anything about that. It's still not clear what doesn't work though, are you saying you're not getting any form data?

Comment: Yes it is CGI stuff, apologies I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is verbatim then I think you have a typo in the first line: did you mean `CONTENT_LENGHT` or is it a typo? ENV[] will return a string if the variable is set, which will upset `STDIN#read`. I get `TypeError: can't convert String into Integer`. Assuming the typo, then `ENV[]` returns `nil`, which tells `STDIN#read` to read until EOF, which from the console means, I think, Control-Z. That might be causing a problem.

I suggest you investigate by modifying your script thus:

```
read_length = ENV["CONTENT_LENGTH"].to_i # assumed typo fixed, convert to integer
puts "read length = #{read_length}"
input = STDIN.read( read_length )
puts "input = #{input}"
puts "Content-type: text/html \n\n" # this seems to serve no purpose

require 'digest/md5'
digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(input)
puts "digest = #{digest}"

# prefer this version: it's more idiomatically "Rubyish"
File.open("register.txt", "a") do |f|
  puts "file opened"
  f.puts(digest)
end

file_content = File.read("register.txt")
puts "done, file content = #{file_content}"
```

This works on my machine, with the following output (when CONTENT_LENGTH set to 12):

```
read length = 12
abcdefghijkl
input = abcdefghijkl
Content-type: text/html

digest = 9fc9d606912030dca86582ed62595cf7
file opened
done, file content = 6cfbc6ae37c91b4faf7310fbc2b7d5e8
e271dc47fa80ddc9e6590042ad9ed2b7
b0fb8772912c4ac0f13525409c2b224e
9fc9d606912030dca86582ed62595cf7
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is a great help, I did forget to mention this is CGI, I get an internal server error without the content-type, when submitting the form i got:
read length = 36 input = Username=abc&Gender=abc&Password=abc digest = 47ff5e5e40fbcced5c2e24702f236235

It did not open the file and append anything.

Comment: I have managed to get it to write to a file now thank you all for your help, and Thank you Mike Woodhouse I did have a typo.